# yolov5 rstp OSError: [WinError 123]

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, yolov5

I used yolov5 with python detect.py --source rtsp://admin:xxxxx@10.xx.xx.xxx//streaming/channels/1 --weights runs/train/exp4/weights/best.pt
but  happened OSError: [WinError 123] Incorrect filename, directory name, or volume tagline method
How to solve this problem？
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

python detect.py --source rtsp://admin:xxxxx@10.xx.xx.xxx//streaming/channels/1

look this

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/pull/9879

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).